# Automatically cycle through web pages

Tags: html, firefox, google-chrome

I'm looking to put together a build monitor display that cycles through various views.
Basically I'm looking for suggestions of an easy way I can get a browser to cycle through a list of urls at regular intervals.

I know I JS is an option but I'm sure there has to be a Chrome or FireFox extensions that already does this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/tab-slideshow/

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/loepeenhjndiclafjgoackjblfhonogb

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/iaehgcjemgeldahhdeafbdeglfbaecll?hl=de

?

Comment: I tried the free Chrome AddOn posted above, but it's not working well. I found https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-slideshow/loepeenhjndiclafjgoackjblfhonogb which is a lot more stable and my preferred AddOn for this now.

Comment: Url slideshow worked well for me https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/url-slideshow/pdblffiahfjjldpkngdpaegghhamefam/related // only wish is that it could take URLs lists directly from my bookmarks

Answer (score 2):

You could use a product like https://www.vuepilot.com which was built for this specific purpose. Dislaying web sites / content on screens.

You can manage the rotation lists / screen content from a central interface and have it synchronise across your screens so you don't need to do it manually.

It's for companies that have a bunch of screens around the office as you can control them all from the online dashboard without needing keyboard, mice etc.

Full disclaimer, i'm the founder of VuePilot, after writing countless scripts and web drivers, I eventually built a product that should tick all the boxes (auto start, remote control, machine sync, power management etc). It's not free, but if you have a bunch of screens to manage, it should save you time and effort.